Database backup fails with cleanuptime option
I've been running this same script for over 2 years now without fail. All the sudden I'm getting the following error. What has happened?
EXEC dbo.DatabaseBackup
  @Databases = 'DB1,DB2',
  @Directory = '\\RemoteShareName\Utilities\WIMS',
  @BackupType = 'FULL',
  @DirectoryStructure = NULL,
  @FileName = '{DatabaseName}_{BackupType}_{Year}{Month}{Day}.{FileExtension}',
  @Verify = 'N',
  @CleanupTime = 8766,
  @CopyOnly = 'Y',
  @Compress = 'Y';

Date and time: 2024-11-01 08:24:26
Server: MYSERVERNAME
Version: 13.0.5888.11
Edition: Standard Edition (64-bit)
Platform: Windows
Procedure: [DBATools].[dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
Parameters: @Databases = 'DB1,DB2', @Directory = '\\RemoteShareName\Utilities\WIMS', @BackupType = 'FULL', @Verify = 'N', @CleanupTime = 8766, @CleanupMode = 'AFTER_BACKUP', @Compress = 'Y', @CopyOnly = 'Y', @ChangeBackupType = 'N', @BackupSoftware = NULL, @CheckSum = 'N', @BlockSize = NULL, @BufferCount = NULL, @MaxTransferSize = NULL, @NumberOfFiles = NULL, @MinBackupSizeForMultipleFiles = NULL, @MaxFileSize = NULL, @CompressionLevel = NULL, @Description = NULL, @Threads = NULL, @Throttle = NULL, @Encrypt = 'N', @EncryptionAlgorithm = NULL, @ServerCertificate = NULL, @ServerAsymmetricKey = NULL, @EncryptionKey = NULL, @ReadWriteFileGroups = 'N', @OverrideBackupPreference = 'N', @NoRecovery = 'N', @URL = NULL, @Credential = NULL, @MirrorDirectory = NULL, @MirrorCleanupTime = NULL, @MirrorCleanupMode = 'AFTER_BACKUP', @MirrorURL = NULL, @AvailabilityGroups = NULL, @Updateability = 'ALL', @AdaptiveCompression = NULL, @ModificationLevel = NULL, @LogSizeSinceLastLogBackup = NULL, @TimeSinceLastLogBackup = NULL, @DataDomainBoostHost = NULL, @DataDomainBoostUser = NULL, @DataDomainBoostDevicePath = NULL, @DataDomainBoostLockboxPath = NULL, @DirectoryStructure = NULL, @AvailabilityGroupDirectoryStructure = '{ClusterName}${AvailabilityGroupName}{DirectorySeparator}{DatabaseName}{DirectorySeparator}{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}', @FileName = '{DatabaseName}_{BackupType}__{Year}{Month}{Day}.{FileExtension}', @AvailabilityGroupFileName = '{ClusterName}${AvailabilityGroupName}_{DatabaseName}_{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}_{Year}{Month}{Day}_{Hour}{Minute}{Second}_{FileNumber}.{FileExtension}', @FileExtensionFull = NULL, @FileExtensionDiff = NULL, @FileExtensionLog = NULL, @Init = 'N', @Format = 'N', @ObjectLevelRecoveryMap = 'N', @ExcludeLogShippedFromLogBackup = 'Y', @DirectoryCheck = 'Y', @StringDelimiter = ',', @DatabaseOrder = NULL, @DatabasesInParallel = 'N', @LogToTable = 'N', @Execute = 'Y'
Version: 2024-10-27 11:48:54
Source: https://ola.hallengren.com
    
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 5, Procedure DatabaseBackup, Line 2283 [Batch Start Line 2]
The value for the parameter @CleanupTime is not supported. Cleanup is not supported if the token {DatabaseName} is not part of the directory.
    
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 6, Procedure DatabaseBackup, Line 2283 [Batch Start Line 2]
The value for the parameter @CleanupTime is not supported. Cleanup is not supported if the token {BackupType} is not part of the directory.
    
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 7, Procedure DatabaseBackup, Line 2283 [Batch Start Line 2]
The value for the parameter @CleanupTime is not supported. Cleanup is not supported if the token {CopyOnly} is not part of the directory.
    
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DatabaseBackup, Line 2283 [Batch Start Line 2]
The documentation is available at https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html.```

